# Excel VBA to copy only non blank rows from specific column

Tags: excel, vba

Making a sheet where the user can select an area from a drop down, and then cells containing info relevant to that area are shown in column T.

The data is formatted in such a way that the areas are the headings across the columns from A1:Q1. Then on each column is a combination of blank cells and cells that contain the info needed.

This shows a simplified example of what I'd like to do. Obviously the X's pertain to actual info.

[image]

I've got a code that I think should work, but it's not.... The first section does successfully find the right column from the sheet using whatever is in the drop down. But then the copy paste loop that looks for blank cells does not seem happy, and doesn't want to use the address I found from the find section.

I did explore the idea of using index/match/array, but couldn't get my head round it.

```
Sub NonBlank()

Dim Found As Range
Dim Clm As String
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim Criteria As Variant
Dim cell As Range





Criteria = Sheets("Example").Range("S3").Value

Set rngSearch = Sheets("Example").Range("A1:Q1")

Set Found = rngSearch.Find(What:=Criteria, _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                               MatchCase:=False)
                               

If Not Found Is Nothing Then

Clm = Found.Address(rowabsolute:=False)


Dim datatocopy As Range
Set datatocopy = Sheets("example").Range("clm").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

If Not datatocopy Is Nothing Then
    datatocopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Example").Range("T3")

End If

End If


End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: The issue is your code uses addresses like `Range("D66")` that we cannot see in your screenshot and therefore it is hard to tell where exactly it is going wrong. Please see [mcve]. It looks like the addresses in the code do not fit to the addresses in the screenshot. Can you clarify this? • What do you expect this to do `Range("T" & lastrow + 1).Value = Range("T" & lastrow + 1).Value`?

Comment: Hello again! I have updated my question with more info, and my code that features your other comment. In answer to your question about this: Range("T" & lastrow + 1).Value = Range("T" & lastrow + 1).Value ..  erm in hindsight I had no idea... hence it is now gone...!

Comment: `Range("clm")` is literally looking for a range which name is `"clm"` if you want to use the value from the variable `clm` you need to change it to `Range(clm)`. Further this is only one cell. But it needs to be the entire range where you expect data. So instead of `Sheets("example").Range("clm").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` try `Found.EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

Comment: AH. I have been pulling out hair over how to fix the use of "found". One last issue, this now also pastes the column title/area. How can I remove?

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much for your patience and clear explanations. I have honestly learnt so much from you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228787/discussion-between-peepdeep-and-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are constants and no formulas you don't need to loop through the data and can just use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` on the range to get all constant values (without the blank cells).

```
Dim DataToCopy As Range
Set DataToCopy = Sheets("Table").Range("B1:B6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

If Not DataToCopy Is Nothing Then
    DataToCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Table").Range("G2")
End If
```

The following should work

```
Sub NonBlank()   
    Dim Criteria As Variant
    Criteria = Sheets("Example").Range("S3").Value

    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Set rngSearch = Sheets("Example").Range("A1:Q1")
    
    Dim Found As Range
    Set Found = rngSearch.Find(What:=Criteria, _
                                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                   MatchCase:=False)

    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        Dim datatocopy As Range
        Set datatocopy = Found.EntireColumn.Resize(RowSize:=Rows.Count-1).Offset(RowOffset:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
        If Not datatocopy Is Nothing Then
            datatocopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Example").Range("T3")
        End If        
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that works really nicely. For the range section I'm trying to get it to use the column it found previously as the starting point for the range. "clm = Found.Address(rowabsolute:=False)" but this doesn't seem to work with it?